# Saving Facebook users profile picture to a folder

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to save the profile pictures of my users into my server, but it only gives me a 0 byte jpg file whenever i execute my code.

here is the first code that i tried but didn't work.

```
$fp = fopen ('fb_profilepic.jpg', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://graph.facebook.com/875644792482183/picture');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow the redirection
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

this is the second code that i got from another thread

```
$fp = fopen ('fb_profilepic.jpg', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init('http://graph.facebook.com/875644792482183/picture');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = '';
if( ($json = curl_exec($ch) ) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow the redirection
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
    curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```

both of them gives me a 0 byte jpg file.[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for

```
file_put_contents("image.jpg",file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/875644792482183/picture"));
```

Comment: It gives me this error

Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:

Comment: make sure it's from http and not https

Answer (score 0):

It look likes that there is a redirect from `http` to `https` and OpenSSL can't handle it due to certificate error. In order to solve this you can do this:

**First:** Check certificate file location which will be in default_cert_file key, you will found it in openssl_get_cert_locations() its php openssl function:

```
$ php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"
Array
(
    [default_cert_file] => /opt/lampp/share/openssl/cert.pem
    [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
    [default_cert_dir] => /opt/lampp/share/openssl/certs
    [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
    [default_private_dir] => /opt/lampp/share/openssl/private
    [default_default_cert_area] => /opt/lampp/share/openssl
    [ini_cafile] => 
    [ini_capath] => 
)
```

**Second:** Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem:

```
$ wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

**Third:** Copy certificate PEM file into default_cert_file location:

```
$ sudo mv cacert.pem /opt/lampp/share/openssl/cert.pem
```

Note that your default_cert_file may point to some place that is different than this.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the same problem doing the opposite, changing http:// to https://.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/875644792482183/picture');
```